# Fast way to change elements in an object list(R)

Tags: r, list, polygons, lapply

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object, and I want to change each individual polygon ID to match a column in the data.frame component. I can get this done with a for loop or lapply, but it takes about one minute per 30 list items, and there are 5500 in total.

Here's what I tried

1 . using lapply:

```
changeID <- function(i) {
tor@polygons[[i]]@ID = as.character(tor$id[i])
return(0)
}

lapply(seq_along(tor@polygons), changeID)
```

2 . using a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:5597) {
tor@polygons[[i]]@ID = as.character(tor$id[i])
}
```

Any ideas for a more efficient solution?

Comment: Does the `spChFIDs` method/tool help? (It's got its own help page).

Comment: I have the same general suggestion as @CarlWitthoft, but typically IDs should match the row names of the associated data.frame, right?